# How can I make an extension method for IEnumerable<T>? Where should I declare it?

Tags: c#

```
public static class Analysis
{
    *//I want to use my extensions methods here. To be more specific,
    //I want to do like this:*
    // var array = new int[]{1,2,3};
    // var newArray = array.MyMethod();

}

public static class IEnumerableExtensions<T>
    where T : IComparable
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> MyMethod(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        *//here is my method
        //yield return .... ;*
    }
}
```

This is the mistake that I get:

> Extension method must be declare in a non-generic static class

I want to be able to use that method for `int[]`, `double[]`, `DateTime[]`...

And I cannot declare this method in my `Analysis` class because it is non-generic.

Comment: The error message says it: Use a *non-generic static class*.

Comment: Make your class non-generic like this: `public static class IEnumerableExtensions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the generic parameter from the class and declare it on the method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions

{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) 
                                           where T : IComparable
    {
        *//here is my method
        //yield return .... ;*
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: I suggest adding `partial` into class declaration: `IEnumerable<T>` can be extended with a lot of methods which can be implemented in different files.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Why would you add `partial`? Extension methods don't care about what `static` class they are declared in.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!